# Exporting a widget into jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a widget that is an extension of a View and can be inserted inside a xml. It does not contain any layout or any other kind of external resource.

It automatically loads its data and prepares to be displaied inside the constructor, and then waits for the parent activity to launch the start() method to start working.

How can I export it as a jar, without the source code, so that I could eventually distribute it and let others use it without modifying it? Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used any layout or drawable or any resource to achieve this?

Comment: No, I made it totally without any external resource on purpose

Comment: I added some more details on the description

Comment: Please check my answer. Try like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right Click on your project>Export>Java>Jar File>**

And select only src and not other folde.
Give your jar file name like widget.

Then Finish.
A jar file will be created with name 'widget.jar'

Hope this help you.

Comment: Wait, it works perfectly in the source, once I created the jar and imported as a lib in the project, but how can I make it appear inside the xml? When it was as source, i could add "it.beppi.<widget>", now I cannot anymore.